# don't work continue statement in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, continue

I used some coding for learn break and continue statement. The break statement working fine but continue statement  not working. I will give my codeing

```
<?php

for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++){

    echo $a;
    echo "<br>";

    if($a==6){
        break;
    }
    else{
        continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the continue is completely useless here. Put your if-else condition above your echo statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your `for` loop, `continue` is the last statement so, nothing is available to skip, as it will automatically go to beginning of the next iteration.

[CONTINUE](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration

[BREAK](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.

```
    for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++){<--------------------┐
                                                 | 
        echo $a;                                 |
        echo "<br>";                             |
        if($a==6){                               |
            break; ----- jumps here ------┐      |
        }                                 |      |                               
                                          |      |
   Remove else `continue` here,it will go |      |
   to the beginning automatically until   |      |
   loop fails -----------------------------------┘
                                          |
    }                                     |      
                     <--------------------┘
```

**AS PER COMMENT:**

```
<?php
    for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++){

    echo $a;
    echo "<br>";

    if($a==6){
        break;
    }
    else{
        echo "before continue <br/>";
        continue;
        echo "after continue <br/>"; // this will not execute because continue goes beginning of the next iteration 
    }

}
```

Comment: How I will use break and continue statement in same for loop ?

Answer (score 3):

`continue` means "skip the rest of the loop and go back to the top of the loop", since your `continue` is the last thing in your loop, there is nothing to skip, so the same thing will happen whether or not the `continue` is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable doesn't hit the `continue` statement. Look at this example:

```
$i = 10;
while (--$i)
{
  if ($i == 8)
  {
    continue;
  }
  if ($i == 5)
  {
    break;
  }
  echo $i . "\n";
}
```

The output will be:

> 9 7 6